# How can I format a column from a GridView before export to show all numbers in excel?

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm trying to export a GridView to Excel and I have a column with a series of numbers like 1245333325364. When I run the query for the GridView I can see the complete number but when I export to excel all I see is 1.00133E+12 on that column. I know I can have the user change this in excel but not all files are being open after export they just save it straight into a directory. I will really like to change the column's format in the export process rather than having the user do it before they save the file. I'm performing the export in C# any help will be really appreciate.

The code I'm using to export the GridView is like so:

```
    protected void exporttoexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");

        PrepareGridViewForExport(GridView1);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + date + "_" + CHROUT.Text + "_Trailer_" + TRAILER.Text);
        Response.Charset = "''";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("width", "105px");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#CCCCCC");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#CCCCCC");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#CCCCCC");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "#CCCCCC");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "#CCCCCC");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[5].Style.Add("background-color", "#CCCCCC");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[6].Style.Add("background-color", "#CCCCCC");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[7].Style.Add("background-color", "#CCCCCC");

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];

            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

            row.Attributes.Add("class", "texmode");

            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                row.Cells[0].Style.Add("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
                row.Cells[1].Style.Add("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
                row.Cells[2].Style.Add("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
                row.Cells[3].Style.Add("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
                row.Cells[4].Style.Add("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
                row.Cells[5].Style.Add("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
                row.Cells[6].Style.Add("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
                row.Cells[7].Style.Add("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
            }
        }
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Does that number still appear when you expand the column in Excel? (Basic question, I know; just checking.)

Comment: If by expand you mean making the cell's width bigger, the answer is no. I still show the scientific format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got the answer for this question. I basically just need to add the format to the GridView before export and to be more specific on the DataBound. Take a look at the code below:

First create an event for the OnRowDataBound

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("class", "text");
        e.Row.Cells[2].Attributes.Add("class", "text");
    }
}
```

Then reference this on the GridView like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
```

Then just add this little line of code right before your export the GridView.

```
Response.Write(style);
```

And that's all.

Comment: But it's not working in my case. Please help. I have a colmn with data like '5E02'. Even after using the above method, it's being exported as '5.00E+02'. What else shall I do? I have tried concatenating (') to it while retrieving from SQL, but then it shows up like ('5E02) instead of (5E02).

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
   protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
    {

    GridView gvExportExcel = new GridView();
                        gvExportExcel.ID = "ExportExcel";
                        gvExportExcel.AllowPaging = false;
                        gvExportExcel.DataSource = listOfData(Generic list);
                        gvExportExcel.DataBind();
                        for (int i = 0; i < gvExportExcel.Rows.Count; i++)
     gvExportExcel.Rows[i].Cells[0].Attributes.Add("style", "mso-number-format:\\@");

                        Export("Test.xls", gvExportExcel);
    }


private void Export(string fileName, GridView dgvExport)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                Response.Charset = string.Empty;
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                dgvExport.RenderControl(htw);

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

            }
            catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException ex)
            {
                //write your exception
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the issue one of the cell's width rather than it's format?  Change the width of the cell and the number should show up fine.

Comment: I tried that already but it's not working. Maybe the code I'm using is bad:

Comment: This is what I'm using to make the width of the cell bigger:         GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Style.Add("width", "105px");

Answer (score 0):

You can set its `CellFormat` as `Number` or `Currency` replace its original format.

Comment: How would I accomplish this? Is this done in the ASP page or code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a Single Quote (') symbol **just before** the big number...  Excel recognises Single Quote as Text.

Alternatively you can try enclosing the value in Double Quotes like this "12345678901234"

Hope this works.