# Convert number to text when exporting to excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am displaying my data(comma separated numbers) in a grid view, and it happens as needed. However, when I export it to excel, then the value is changed in terms of display

e.g  my value is 901155465, 978785496, 987458986 
Then it appears as 901,155,465,978,785,496,987,458,986

This is how I pass the data set into an excel. I know we can render the HTML also, but I needed to transfer the data only.

```
GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet;
GridView1.DataBind();
string style = @" .text { mso-number-format:\@; }  "; 
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
esponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
System.IO.StringWriter s_Write = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter h_write = new HtmlTextWriter(s_Write);
GridView1.ShowHeader = true;
GridView1.RenderControl(h_write);
Response.Write(style); 
Response.Write(s_Write.ToString());
Response.End();
```

It seems excel is treating the number as one number and adding comma at appropriate places.

Is there any solution to display data as shown in gridview.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you exporting to excel?

Comment: I am using the Page.Response to add an excel

Comment: Edit your question to show how you are exporting it to excel. You can write binary(for example with EPPlus) or a html table (RenderControl the GridView). That's a great difference. Sidenote: If this is an ASP.NET question, tag it accordingly.

Comment: I have added the part as to how I pass the data to excel

Answer (score 12):

try this:

```
_worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "=\"" + YOUR_VALUE + "\"";
```

that's how I did using Interop.Excel

Excel will ignore the (=) since it starts a formula and the double quotes will tell excel to use that value as a String.

Comment: Are you suggesting I add extra characters in the value(=, and quotes). I cannot concatenate values within the data.

Comment: Excel will ignore the (=) and the quotes will tell excel to use that value as a String.

Answer (score 8):

You could try to export the excel stylesheet also:

```
mso-number-format:"0"   NO Decimals
```

http://cosicimiento.blogspot.fr/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html

Therefor you need to write it to the `Response`:

```
// ...
string style = @"<style> td { mso-number-format:"0"; } </style> ";
// Style is added dynamically
Response.Write(style);
Response.Write(s_Write.ToString());
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

try this it work fine

for (int i = 0; i < gvExportExcel.Rows.Count; i++)
 gvExportExcel.Rows[i].Cells[0].Attributes.Add("style", "mso-number-format:\@");

Comment: Thanks Rissa. I tried this solution but it did not have affect on the desired cell. I used the solution mentioned in the link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905121/how-can-i-format-a-column-from-a-gridview-before-export-to-show-all-numbers-in-e

Answer (score 0):

This issue haunted me for like a year this helped me. I tried many solutions stackoverflow.com but it didn't help. Hope this helps someone

```
Dim formatRange As Excel.Range
formatRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("a1", "b1")
formatRange.NumberFormat = "@"
```

To put data in cell A1

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "098"
```

or if you are copying from a datagridview

```
xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial("Text", False, False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, True)
```

http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_page_format.htm
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
"\"\t" + value?.ToString() + "\"";
```

anyone can use this line of code, if you need to convert and export number or any value as it is.

For my case, 
    value = "13291440533000102";
When I was trying to export using StreamWriter, the value was exported correctly in CSV format. But during opening the .csv file, the excel was treating the value as number. And as the number is more than 16 characters, it was converted like 13291440533000100. Last char was changed. I have solved this by this was.